# Is it possible to make jDateChooser password protected?

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

I am creating a jDateChooser in a Java Swing App that I want to be only accessible by admins.  I have a dialog that prompts for the Admin Password, called "PromptForAdminPasswordDialog," which I would like to launch for validation every time the user clicks the button or within the text field of the jDateChooser.  Any idea of how I can do this?

Comment: Um, just launch the dialog when the user clicks the button? What have you tried? Where is your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Recommended reading: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Call the validation in the button action listener prior to showing the date chooser (obviously).